# Get header in genfromtxt when using skip_header

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I have data I want to plot  and analyse, looking like:

```
0101 
1  3
2  4
3  6
```

I use skip_header in genfromtxt to load the file 2 column data, however I also need the header for reference.

Is there a way to get the header back?

Comment: Use a regular Python file read to get that line,

Comment: For `genfrontxt` this isn't a valid column header.  So are right to skip it.  And there's no provision for saving or recording skipped lines. Why should there  be?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is implemented in numpy.genfromtxt(). You may have to call the function twice, once for the header, and a second time for the data. Or you may want to have a look at the functions offered by pandas, such as [read_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html#pandas.read_table).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=" ")
```

So that the first line is read as header